# Apple APNs push notification is not working

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

My team is using the Apple push notifications for the last 7 years which was working like a Gem. Recently generated builds in both the Development certificate and the App Store certificate are not receiving notifications.

The notification is sent from the PHP code.

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '****************';
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = '******';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Hi User!';
//$message =$_REQUEST['message'];
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'cert.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

/* Open a connection to the APNS server*/
 $fp = stream_socket_client(
 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
 $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );


// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
 $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
echo $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
?>
```

The Push notification results as a success. But the App is not receiving the notification. Is there any new update in this code? Is there any chance for errors in receiving notifications on the device?

Answer (score 0):

If you was sending push using p12 or pem file then it's stopped.

You have to use new way using P8 files

Check below link for further details.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/

Comment: We are using pem file and I was not aware it was stopped. The preexisting pem file in Production is working(Maybe the old one is still supported).  I saw the link early, there was no info about pem, p12 or p8 files in this. Can you help me with details when Apple stopped support to pem files